# Online Perl POD renderer

Tags: perl, perl-pod

I seem to remember an "offical" site (perl.org or cpan.org) which had a POD previewer. One uploaded a file and it would display the contained POD as it would appear on CPAN. Does someone have this link. I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[metacpan.org](https://metacpan.org/)'s online POD preview is at https://metacpan.org/pod2html.  Either paste the POD in the textarea or click the "Browse for file .." button, select the POD file you want to preview (which may be a `.pm` file including Perl code) and click "Render".

Comment: @Joel, Note that [`pod2html`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pod2html) is command line tool that's part of the core Perl distribution.

Comment: @ikegami, yes, but search.cpan.org uses some custom CSS.  Also, different versions of pod2html may produce different results.  Using the online version shows you how search.cpan.org will display your POD.

Comment: @BillRuppert, please read the question.  The link is not to documentation, but to a live web service that does not exist (AFAIK) on MetaCPAN.

Comment: @cjm Sorry for the confusion, trying to help move links from search.cpan.org to metacpan.org. Obviously I need to pay more attention. I didn't know about that functionality, very nice.

Comment: @BillRuppert a noble cause (moving links)! Keep it up (this case excepted). It's too bad that MetaCPAN does not have such a service, I would make use of it.

Answer (score 7):

For an **offline** Pod renderer in the style of [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/) have a look at [pod2cpanhtml](https://metacpan.org/pod/pod2cpanhtml).

Answer (score 2):

This question is about CPAN POD rendering, but it was also the top Google search for me for an online POD renderer not just an official one. In addition to CPAN's official one, there's an on-the-fly renderer written by Michał Wojciechowski that I've found super-helpful:

http://podwebview.odyniec.net/

He wrote a [blog post about it](http://blogs.perl.org/users/michal_wojciechowski/2013/10/pod-web-view.html) and put the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/odyniec/POD-Web-View), in case the above link ever stops working.